# Unique constraint using SQL Server CAST([column] AS DATE) function

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, unique-constraint

I have an `appointments` table that has (among others) a `[personid]` and an `[appdate]` column of `datetime(2)` datatype. I want to add a constraint that will prevent any `personid` from getting more than one appointment on any single day.

I tried this but it did not work

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblappointments
    ADD CONSTRAINT SingleApp UNIQUE (PersonID, CAST(Appdate AS DATE))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you can create a computed column and use it as the index.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblappointments ADD AppointmentDay as CAST(Appdate AS DATE) PERSISTED
```

If you don't use `PERSISTED` the value will be calculated every time the column is accessed

Comment: It is not necessary to mark it as `PERSISTED`. It will be `PERSISTED` in the unique index anyway irrespective of this

Comment: @MartinSmith Correct. Forgot the idea is to have a unique index. But my habit is always to make CT Persisted when they are required to be so.

Comment: Thank you, that would work, However, I prefer a method that will not wast storage. I tried to use a user-defined function that would check whether a personid has an appointment on a certain day and use that function as check constraint, but I could not make that work either.

Comment: @SchwanAbdulkareem - just don't mark the column as persisted then. It will then work much the same way as the syntax in your question would (if that was supported)